# Can Black capitalize?

Tags: analysis

I have played a game against a computer and came to the following position:

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "1"]
[fen "3q2k1/pp1r1p1p/2p1p1p1/2Pr2P1/P2P1P2/4Q3/1P1R3P/3R2K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

I gave my best to capitalize, but in the end game was spectacularly drawn (3 queens were on the board at some point, but I have managed to save myself with perpetual check).

I feel sad because I believe that Black should be able to win the game from the position above.

Can you demonstrate a winning plan from this position?

Comment: What did you try? After 1...b6, Black can win a pawn to start with.

Comment: @Wes: I went for `...Qa5` with subsequent `e5` but misplayed it afterwards...

Comment: @ALNS, Qa5 was my first thought in the position, to prevent b4, but then I realized that it destroys the "Alekhine's Gun" formation bearing down on the d-pawn and the two defending rooks behind it. Then after b6, cxb6, axb6, Black's c5 is not so dangerous, because White can play Rd3 first to prepare for it and then take on c5.

Comment: @Wes: I have upvoted your answer, but I will officially accept it if I manage to convert the extra pawn. Give me time to play this vs computer and please be patient. I have impossible deadline to finish 3 projects and the last thing I can think right now is chess. I hope you understand...

Comment: @ALNS, no worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After **1...b6!** Black can win a pawn. Whether that will be a winning endgame or not is a different matter, but I don't see a better plan for Black. So **1...b6** looks like the most reasonable way to pursue a win.

```
[FEN "3q2k1/pp1r1p1p/2p1p1p1/2Pr2P1/P2P1P2/4Q3/1P1R3P/3R2K1 b - - 0 1"]
[White "Comp"]
[Black "ALNS"]

1... b6 2. cxb6 (2. b4 a5 3. cxb6 axb4 4. Rc1 Qxb6 5. Rc4 b3 6. Rb2 Rxd4 7.
Rxd4 (7. Rxb3 Rd1+ 8. Kg2 R7d2+ 9. Kf3 Qd8) 7... Qxd4 8. Qxd4 Rxd4 9. Rxb3 Rxa4
10. Rf3 Kf8) 2... axb6 3. b4 (3. Kf1 c5 4. Qe4 cxd4) (3. Rc2 c5 4. Rc4
cxd4) 3... c5 4. bxc5 bxc5 5. h4 cxd4
```

Comment: Analyzed briefly with an engine. Black seems to convert this into win but good technique is required. Excellent position for practice... Thanks again, best regards :)